# how to update the contain in .txt file java

Tags: java, file, text, file-io, io

for example i have the file named `file.txt` which contain personal information (id,name, salary):

```
A123 Anna 3000
A234 Alex 4000
A986 Jame 5000
```

How can I write a java code that allow user to enter an ID of a person and replenish salary?
The final output will look like:

Enter ID: A123

Enter replenish salary: 2000

file.txt after run the program:

```
A123 Anna 5000
A234 Alex 4000
A986 Jame 5000
```

This is what i have done so far but it didnt work:

```
public static void addDalary() throws IOException {
        String ID, Nanme;
        double salary;


            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter ID : ");
            String pID = console.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter replenish salary: ");
            replenish = console.nextInt();

            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                ID = input.next();
                Name = input.next();
                salary = input.nextDouble();

                if (ID == pID) {    
                    salary = salary + replenish;
                }
            }
            input.close();
        }
```

Im new to these things. Any help would be much appreciate.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Comment: See [So, You Need to Write a Program but Don't Know How to Start](http://www.patriciashanahan.com/beginner.html) & get back to us when you have a *specific* question.

Comment: The best way to do it is with the RandonAccessFile class. 
Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199847/random-access-file-in-java

Comment: may be im so dumb but i think the random access file is something relate to the length or file size, it isnt what i want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the approach of reading it from the original file line by line. Search and replace the salary with the new number. Write the content to a new temp file. Delete the original file. Finally replace the temp file to the original file name. Here is the code to do that:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileContentUpdater {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String ID, Name;
        double salary;
        int replenish;

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter ID : ");
        String pID = console.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter replenish salary: ");
        replenish = console.nextInt();

        File originalFile = new File("file.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(originalFile));

        // Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original
        // filename.
        File tempFile = new File("tempfile.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

        String line = null;
        // Read from the original file and write to the new
        // unless content matches data to be removed.
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if (line.contains(pID)) {
                String strCurrentSalary = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(" "), line.length());
                if (strCurrentSalary != null || !strCurrentSalary.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    int replenishedSalary = Integer.parseInt(strCurrentSalary.trim()) + replenish;
                    System.out.println("replenishedSalary : " + replenishedSalary);
                    line = line.substring(0,line.lastIndexOf(" ")) + replenishedSalary;
                }

            }
            pw.println(line);
            pw.flush();
        }
        pw.close();
        br.close();

        // Delete the original file
        if (!originalFile.delete()) {
            System.out.println("Could not delete file");
            return;
        }

        // Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
        if (!tempFile.renameTo(originalFile))
            System.out.println("Could not rename file");

    }
}
```

Comment: yay, finally....., thank u very much

Comment: @Juned please what is the implication of the `pw.fluch();` line?

Comment: what is meaning of storing all data in temp file and writing more data and then transferring it to base file. Not desired solution

Comment: This will not work if you are using client server architecture or if the file has 10lack records it will not work

Comment: @jan_kiran where was that requirement in the question?

Answer (score 4):

One possible way can be like this

1. Read each line from file
2. Split the line
3. prepare another line with updated data and write to temp file
4. Finally delete your old file and rename temp file to old file.
5. Now you are done.
   Try the above algorithm.