# How to get the updated file text

Tags: java

I am making a JFrame from where the user will be able to insert new methods in the file. If the file is not there, program will create the new file and then insert the method there. If the file is already there, it will try to create the new method with the given name but if the file contains the method with the same name, it'll give user the alert.

I am able to do all these things properly, only problem is after creating the new method in the class file, if the user again click on the Create Method button, application does not throws any alert as it is unable to read the new method name from the file. When I check the file content, I can see the new method there but somehow my code is not able to read the new code from the file. Here is the code for the same.

```
    File f = null;
    f = new File(Report.path + "//src//_TestCases//" + tc_name + ".java");

    if (!f.exists()) {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
        f.createNewFile();
        bw.write(testcase);
        bw.close();
    }

        Class<?> c = Class.forName("_TestCases." + tc_name);
        Method[] m = c.getDeclaredMethods();

   for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            if (m[i].getName().toLowerCase()
                    .equals(module_name.toLowerCase())) {

                JOptionPane
                        .showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Module with the given name already exists. Please provide other name.");
                return false;
            }
        }

    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(f.toPath(),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    String text = "";
    if (lines.contains("    @AfterClass")) {
        text = "    @AfterClass";
    } else {
        text = "@AfterClass";
    }

    lines.add(lines.indexOf(text), "@Test\npublic void " + module_name
            + "() throws Exception {\n");
    Files.write(f.toPath(), lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    for (int i = 0; i < tc_values.size(); i++) {
        lines.add(lines.indexOf(text), tc_values.get(i));
        Files.write(f.toPath(), lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    lines.add(lines.indexOf(text), "\n}\n");
    Files.write(f.toPath(), lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: are you reopen the file in the create method code?

Comment: Whatever the code is I have mentioned it above and Creating a new method is not an issue. I am able to create new method, issue is reading those newly created methods from the file.

Comment: Have you tried re-opening the file. I mean after you create the new method, close the file and then open it again. I came up with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383578/how-to-update-the-contain-in-txt-file-java googling

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue was but when I changed the logic of getting the method name from the file, it worked for me. Used scanner to read the file contents and get the method name, earlier was using the below line to get the method name from the file.

```
 Method[] m = c.getDeclaredMethods();
```