# Java - split and replace certain data in text file

Tags: java

I have a text file that contain :

custmerID, firstName, lastName, Count are header and not include in the text file

using spilt to store each records into an array called result

CustomerID    FirstName    LastName     Count
1001;Ho;Wai Hong;0;

Count is use for if the customer choose "Wax & Polish" prefer service, then update the text file count from 0 to 1, from 1 to 2 if customer choose the "Wax & Polish" prefer service again and so on...

```
public void checkDiscount (String preferService, String custID) {
        if(preferService.equals("Wax & Polish")) {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
                String fileName = "customer.txt";
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                String line = null;
                try {
            //read file
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            //read all from the file
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] result = line.split(";");

                if(custID.equals(result[0])) {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    String newCount = result.replaceAll(result[3], (String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(result[3]) + 1)));

        }
    }   
} catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR!");
    }
        }
    }
```

So my problem here is i can't update the count in the text file. How can i do that? Sorry for my bad English, if any things do not understand i will answer it. Appreciate for the answer thank you.

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258714/use-java-to-modify-file-contents-in-place

Comment: This question is also good, very understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383578/how-to-update-the-contain-in-txt-file-java