# How can I create a Random Access File record without specifying the number of records?

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

Here the registration number is given as 100, what I want is;

**Instead of determining the number of records from the beginning, I want the number of records to increase as I add records.**

I will exemplify what I want to tell through arrays;

**Not so;**

```
Array[100];
Array[0]=data;
```

**Like this;**

```
Array[];
Array.push(data);
```

```
import com.deitel.jhtp6.ch24.RandomAccessAccountRecord;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class CreateRandomFile {
    private static final int NUMBER_RECORDS = 100;

    public void createFile() {
        RandomAccessFile file = null;
        try {
            file = new RandomAccessFile("clients.dat", "rw");
            RandomAccessAccountRecord blankRecord = new RandomAccessAccountRecord();
            for (int count = 0; count < NUMBER_RECORDS; count++) 
                blankRecord.write(file);
            System.out.println("Created file clients.dat.");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            System.err.println("Error processing file.");
            System.exit(1);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (file != null) 
                    file.close();
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                System.err.println("Error closing file.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It can be done by counting the number of recordings and adding +1 each time, but this is not practical or professional at all.

Comment: Please [edit] your source code to fix the indentation. It is difficult to see which block starts where and where it ends.

Comment: i'm unclear on your question.  are you asking how to append records to the file instead of  replacing the contents each time?   if so then you'll need to `.seek(..)` to the end of the file after you open it

Comment: See this post with an implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199847/random-access-file-in-java

Comment: @stu It creates a fixed size here, so it's the opposite of what I said.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the number of the records in advance, then you should not use a for loop, but rather a different construct. A while loop with a check if  there are still accounts records to write to file left would do for example.
I don't understand the code logic though, you initialise one instance of
`RandomAccessAccountRecord blankRecord = new RandomAccessAccountRecord();` and then call the write method on the same instance hundred times?

I don't get this one either:

> Not so; Array[100]; Array[0]=data;
>
> Like this; Array[]; Array.push(data);

Does that mean that you need a data structure which will be initialised as empty and you would dynamically add elements? Then array is not the best choice for that.

Comment: YES;
(Does that mean that you need a data structure which will be initialised as empty and you would dynamically add elements? )



No; (Then array is not the best choice for that.)
I just gave an example using arrays to describe what I want.

Comment: Another example;

A chair will be placed in a classroom,
It is unknown how many students are in this class.

I mean;
As students come to the classroom (as new records are added) a chair should be placed (the database inflates).

Comment: So you need a dynamic data structure. Array is not the good fit for that as you need to initialise with some length and once you hit the limit, you need to resize it, which means creating a new array and copying everything. 
There are other things to consider when choosing the correct data structure, do you need a random access to any element based on index or you'll be just appending and reading from its head or the last element?
I suggest you check on data structures like linked list, queue, stack etc.

Comment: *As students come to the classroom (as new records are added) a chair should be placed* Solution: *append* a record to a file. `file.seek(file.length());filledRecord.write(file);`

Comment: @g00se 
Yes it can be like this
So, can this be solved with a database management system?
In other words, we will send the data and the database will detect this and create +1 more empty record and fill it.

Comment: Well...yes. That's how a SQL insert works

Comment: So how should i use (file.seek) then. (without defining size).
I can't find any sample code on the internet for this exact issue. What should I call?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *without defining size*. All files have a size - even if it's zero

Comment: No. So without this definition;
private static final int NUMBER_RECORDS = 100;

Comment: You don't need that defined at all . Just use the code i showed you